# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent') es lo que me sale al tratar de editar un nombre mediante un prompt

Tags: javascript, html5

mi codigo de js es este:

```
let nombre1 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre`);

document.getElementById(int1).textContent = "${nombre1}";
```

y mi html es:

```
<!doctype Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>La Milla Dorada</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Mi idea es que el usuario personalize el checkbox-->
        <section >
                <h1 class="titulo">La Milla Dorada</h1>
                <h2 class="sub-titulo">Sub-Titulo</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="imagenes">
            <div class="Bar1">
                <img class="imagen" src="media/vecteezy_beer_1201116.png" >
                <h4>Antares</h4>
                <h5>Direccion</h5>
                <form method="get">   
                    <div id="int1">Example Text</div>
                    <div id="int2">Example Text</div>
                    <div id="int3">Example Text</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="Bar2">
                <img class="imagen" src="media/vecteezy_beer_1201116.png" >
                <h4>Vertical</h4>
                <h5>Direccion</h5>
                <form method="get">   
                    <div id="int1">Example Text</div>
                    <div id="int2">Example Text</div>
                    <div id="int3">Example Text</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
     <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</html>
```

mi idea es que mediante un promt el usuario pueda editar "los example text" poniendo el nombre de los integrantes y que este se aplique a cada div de igual manera.
pero me tira un error o solo lo aplica al primer div.

Comment: El error que te da es que no encuentra ningún elemento con el id int1. Puede ser porque lo tienes sin las comillas y es una variable no se, porque no se si tienes todo el código puesto

Comment: Si, bueno, tienes dos errores de sintaxis... las comillas como indica @Suso, y despues esto `"${nombre1}";` tampoco lo resuelve bien, pero en mi respuesta omito toda esa línea para darte otra solución basada en clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los **id** nunca deben repetirse. Usa clases comunes si necesitas compartir eventos o cosas entre distintos elementos, no **id**.

Por lo tanto, prueba con esto:

```js
let nombre1 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre1`);
let nombre2 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre2`);
let nombre3 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre3`);

cambiaDivs('.int1', nombre1)
cambiaDivs('.int2', nombre2)
cambiaDivs('.int3', nombre3)

function cambiaDivs(selector, nombre) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.textContent = nombre;
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>La Milla Dorada</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Mi idea es que el usuario personalize el checkbox-->
        <section >
                <h1 class="titulo">La Milla Dorada</h1>
                <h2 class="sub-titulo">Sub-Titulo</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="imagenes">
            <div class="Bar1">
                <img class="imagen" src="media/vecteezy_beer_1201116.png" >
                <h4>Antares</h4>
                <h5>Direccion</h5>
                <form method="get">   
                    <div class="int1">Example Text</div>
                    <div class="int2">Example Text</div>
                    <div class="int3">Example Text</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="Bar2">
                <img class="imagen" src="media/vecteezy_beer_1201116.png" >
                <h4>Vertical</h4>
                <h5>Direccion</h5>
                <form method="get">   
                    <div class="int1">Example Text</div>
                    <div class="int2">Example Text</div>
                    <div class="int3">Example Text</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
     <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Cambios realizados:

1. Se han cambiado los **id** por **class** en los div de los formularios
2. Se han agregado los prompts necesarios para los distintos div que contienen clases comunes:

```
    let nombre1 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre1`);
    let nombre2 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre2`);
    let nombre3 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre3`);
```

3. Se ha creado una función que va a recibir la clase a cambiar y el valor a modificar en el textContent del div que tenga esa clase:

```
    function cambiaDivs(selector, nombre) {
```

4. Dentro de la función, usando [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y luego [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) se han recorrido todos los elementos deseados y modificado su `textContent`.
5. Invocamos la función para cada uno de los casos que necesitamos:

```
    cambiaDivs('.int1', nombre1)
    cambiaDivs('.int2', nombre2)
    cambiaDivs('.int3', nombre3)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias es mi primer pagina y aun estoy aprendiendo jajaja y si en caso de querer remplasar los otros nombre como deberia hacer?

Comment: Todos estamos aprendiendo, esto no se termina nunca :-)  A ver, en cuanto a las otras clases, pues viene a ser lo mismo, fíjate cual de ellas quieres cambiar y sustituyela aqui: `const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".int1");` (donde en lugar de poner la clase `.int1` puedes poner la `.int2` o la `.int3`).

Comment: claro pero me da error el elements y el for each me sustituye solo el int1

Comment: No lo debes estar haciendo bien.  Mira [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/vnqL1x8u/) donde he puesto tu código con el unico cambio del `.int2` por el `.int1` y funciona bien.  Juega con ese fiddle lo que quieras para tus pruebas (abre la consola a mano izquierda pulsando sobre la palabra "Console (beta)" para ver los errores si los hay)

Comment: let nombre1 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre`);
let nombre2 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre`);
let nombre3 = prompt(`Cual es tu nombre`);

const elements =    
    document.querySelectorAll(".int1");
    document.querySelectorAll(".int2");
    document.querySelectorAll(".int3");

;

elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.textContent = nombre1;
});
elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.textContent = nombre2;
});
elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.textContent = nombre3;
});mi idea es que salgan 3 prompt e indique cada example text correspondiente

Comment: Todo eso lo deberias haber puesto en la pregunta inicial, ahora no vamos a cambiar ni la pregunta ni la respuesta para no liar al que venga despues a consultarla.  De todos modos, la solución a tu nuevo problema la tienes creando una función, tal como puedes ver que he hecho [en este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/bp40y6tL/)

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, actualiza la página para verla. En cierto modo si que lo pedias, aunque tan solo habias probado con el primer caso, no con el resto, por eso no lo tuve en cuenta en mi anterior respuesta.

Comment: te voy a hacer un monumento muchisimas gracias,me ayudaste mucho.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido :-)  Saludos